# Non correctly symbols in database at import with text importer

Tags: oracle, encoding

I use Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production" I create table in database for analyze data in her. 
My DDL query for create table:

```
CREATE TABLE RS_DOCUMENT_SEGMENT (
   subject_id NUMBER,
   id NUMBER,
   Type NUMBER(10),
   series NVARCHAR2(20),
   numberID NVARCHAR2(20),
   IssueDate VARCHAR2(100),
   IssueAuthority NVARCHAR2(1000)
)
```

Before import data in my table with help "Text importer" I have column IssueAuthoriity with these data:
[image]

But so I have correctly information with correctly reflection symbols in this column.

Query SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters; shows me this information:
[image]

I think what it may be from due to value type or length: NVARCHAR2(1000) but for now I non checked.

May be someone to expirieced such?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is caused by your nls_characterset CL8ISO8859p5.

This nls_characterset defines the string output of the oracle database.

It should be used for "ISO 8859-4 North and North-East European".

My the suggestion is change the nls_characterset to VALUE AL32UTF8

To change the nls_characterset you can execute an alter database command, but 
be beware that this can make your data corrupt:

```
alter database character set AL32UTF8;
```

You must then bounce the database for the change to take effect.
It is also a best practice to take a full backup before changing nls_characterset.

Comment: Thanks for answer my friend! But i can't change database because I don't enter in group Owner and same I can't alter database same database is an production workspace. Thanks and Good luck!:)

Answer (score 0):

I soleved the problem. Problem was in charset when import data. I changed charset on UTF-8 and data was sucsessful importing and with normally charset.

[image]